# Enable update management for automation account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to link automation account with log analytics and enable update management with below arm template. The resources are getting linked, however not enabling update management. Am I missing something in code

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces','Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts','Dev-Automationaccount')]"
            ],
            "name": "Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace/automation",
            "properties": {
                "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', 'Dev-Automationaccount')]"
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/linkedServices",
            "location": "CentralIndia",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please find below the updated code. This is executing succesfully, but as mentioned, update management is unable to found

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "Dev-Automationaccount",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Basic"
                }
            },
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "Automation Account.",
                "provider": "Kyniac"
            },
            "comments": "The automation account for  LogAnalytics WorkSpace",
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "location": "UK South",
            "apiVersion": "2021-06-22"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace",
            "properties": {
                "features": {
                    "searchVersion": 1
                },
                "sku": {
                    "retentionInDays": 120,
                    "resourcePermissions": true,
                    "heartbeatTableRetention": 90,
                    "name": "pergb2018"
                }
            },
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "LAWorkspace for storing all the logs and metrics.",
                "provider": "Kyniac"
            },
            "comments": "LAWorkspace for storing all the logs and metrics.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
            "location": "UK South",
            "apiVersion": "2021-12-01-preview"
        },
        {
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces','Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts','Dev-Automationaccount')]"
            ],
            "name": "Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace/automation",
            "properties": {
                "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', 'Dev-Automationaccount')]"
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/linkedServices",
            "location": "UK South",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01"
        },
        {
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', 'Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace')]"
            ],
            "name": "Updates(Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace)",
            "properties": {
                "workspaceResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', 'Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace')]"
            },
            "plan": {
                "name": "Updates(Dev-Loganalyticsworkspace)",
                "product": "OMSGallery/Updates",
                "publisher": "Microsoft",
                "promotionCode": " "
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
            "location": "UK South",
            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i have tested your latest ARM template in my local environment it is working fine and i am able to see update management is enabled and a log analytics solution  got created without any issues. Please find the below screenshots for reference : https://i.imgur.com/tK0y27o.png
https://i.imgur.com/Ov0ENJP.png
https://i.imgur.com/FfrcODH.png

Comment: Are you able to see the update management enabled? For me, ehrn i click on update management tab from portal, it throws "not found" error

Comment: see my first screenshot that is shared in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running your shared arm template in my local visual studio using the PowerShell cmdlet `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` Template validation is falling with below error.

```
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 14:51:17 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/<automationAccount>' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.
```

You need to create log analytics solution to enable update management of automation account with log analytics.

I have made the necessary changes to your ARM template that you have shared earlier:

**Here is the ARM template:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "automationAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workspaceName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
        "updates": {
            "name": "[concat('Updates', '(', parameters('workspaceName'), ')')]",
            "galleryName": "Updates"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
            "apiVersion": "2021-12-01-preview",
            "name":"[parameters('workspaceName')]",
            "location":"westus",
            "properties":{
                "sku": {
                    "name": "PerGB2018"
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type":"Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
                    "apiVersion":"2015-11-01-preview",
                    "location":"westus",
                    "name": "[variables('updates').name]",
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/', variables('updates').name)]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "workspaceResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'))]"
                    },
                    "plan": {
                        "name": "[variables('updates').name]",
                        "publisher": "Microsoft",
                        "promotionCode": "",
                        "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', variables('updates').galleryName)]"
                    }
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-06-22",
            "name":"[parameters('automationAccountName')]",
            "location":"westus",
            "properties":{
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Basic"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('workspaceName'),'/','Automation')]",
            "dependsOn":[
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces',parameters('workspaceName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts',parameters('automationAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "location":"westus",
            "properties": {
                "resourceId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/',parameters('automationAccountName'))]"
            }

        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

I have tested the above ARM template and it is working fine from my end. I would suggest you to test it from your end as well.

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh for your response. I made some modifications to my script as per your update and deployed and it got deployed succesfully. However when i check the update management , i am getting "not found error"

Comment: @Sajith when you trigger the deployment from local, in the portal in deployment status page were you able to see a log analytics solution got created as shown below 
https://i.imgur.com/SrvLB51.png
using your template